# How to import morph targets into Blender?

Tags: import, three.js

I'm trying to import a js file with morph targets into Blender(v2.65) using the three.js(r66) importer, but it seems that the importer plug-in is not working properly, because nothing is shown in the scene. I tried to convert the js into an obj file and then import it into Blender, but only the mesh was imported, the morph targets were not imported. Can someone help me please?

JS File: three.js/examples/models/skinned/UCS/umich_ucs.js

Comment: One possible way is to import 1 mesh. Create a shape key as a base shape key. Import a second compatible mesh. Select the second mesh, and then shift+select the original base mesh, and on shape keys panel, click "Join as Shapes". Repeat to join all shape keys to 1 base mesh.

Comment: But there is only one .js file with one mesh and five morph targets.

Comment: Sorry I should have clarified that somehow you need to convert the shapes into OBJ files. The THREE exporter is finicky enough, the importer I imagine is even more difficult. Try experimenting with ALL the option combinations.

Comment: Do you know any tutorial that teaches how to convert shape keys into OBJ files?

Comment: If you know how to program you could write a python script to import the JSON file and output an OBJ file (which is a text file format) using each vertex buffer, and the face index buffer values.

Comment: I tried to use the OBJExporter.js, but it only generated one OBJ file.

Comment: Try using THREE js to shift to one of the morph targets, then export. Does the OBJ represent that morph target? Or just the original mesh?

Comment: The OBJ file represents the original mesh, because when I import this OBJ into Blender, only the mesh appears in the scene, there is no morph targets. And I am not sure if I understand what you meant when you wrote: "Try using THREE js to shift to one of the morph targets, then export".

Comment: could you upload the files?

Comment: It worked, I finally managed to import the morph targets! And I used beiller's suggestion of clicking the "Join as Shapes" option. Thank you!

Comment: I've posted relevant comments as answer. Cheers!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One possible way is to import 1 mesh. Create a shape key as a base shape key. Import a second compatible mesh. Select the second mesh, and then shift+select the original base mesh, and on shape keys panel, click "Join as Shapes". Repeat to join all shape keys to 1 base mesh.

Try using THREE js to shift to one of the morph targets, then export multiple OBJ files and join them all in blender.